# Using adjectives as nouns

Tags: nouns, adjectives

What is the term for using an adjective in the place of a noun?

It seems to come up a lot in fantasy fiction, generally used as a proper noun to describe a group ("the Twisted", "the Hunted"), but it also comes up in everyday use ("the mentally ill").

Comment: The term *substantive adjective* may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammatically, Quirk, Greenbaum, Leech and Svartvik (1985) describe this as adjectives functioning as heads of noun phrases' (7.23—7.26, pp 421—424).

Rhetorically, this is a combination of **ellipsis** (the omission of a word or phrase which is easily understood in context) and  **metonymy** (referring to something or someone by one of its/their attributes).